# Нужен сложный парсер с подстановкой IP

Tags: ip, парсер

Я с непростой задачей - парсить нужно информацию с профиля пользователя, который он добровольно(!) нам открыл, но сервис банит парсер по IP (вернее профиль человека). Нужна подстановка IP user-a для логина парсера, с которого он логинился ранее. Есть ли сервисы прокси, которые позволяют такое делать? Или вообще какой-то способ?

Answer (score 2):

Не получится при обращении к серверу подставлять IP, с которого было обращение пользователя.

Прокси серверы дают возможность маскировать свой IP, подменяя его своим. Но есть не анонимные прокси, которые отсылают адрес маскирующегося специальным заголовком `X-Forwarded-For`.

Сервер может Вас банить из-за частого обращения, считая их DDoS атакой. Попробуйте сделать задержку отправки, на секунду или более.

Ещё, если у сервиса, на который вы пытаетесь зайти есть API - можно упростить себе и серверу жизнь) Если скажете что за сервис, можно подумать ещё.